# how to insert onClick event in html string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, reactjs

I am trying add onClick method to html string and then adding it to html element using insertAdjacentHTML

```
function renderHtml(sendMessage, userId) {
  return `<div class="message-data" onClick='${() => 
  sendMessage(userId)}'>message</div>`
}
let htmlString = renderHtml(this.sendMessage, userId);
document.querySelector('#message-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString );
```

how can i pass my function in this html.

Comment: And what has this to do with either Angular or React?

Comment: I am using this in react

Comment: Why would you be doing this in React?

Answer (score 0):

Add an id property to your div

```
function renderHtml(sendMessage, userId) {
  return `<div id="somethingUnique" class="message-data" >message</div>`
}
let htmlString = renderHtml(this.sendMessage, userId);
document.querySelector('#message-container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString );
```

and then add an event like this

```
var element= document.getElementById("somethingUnique");
element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  sendMessage(userId);
});
```

this is ReactJs btw, but solution will be same in angularsince they both are JS only syntax can be different.